# How to securely store a password used for 3rd party service on my website

Tags: node.js, security, password-protection

I have a website I created with a nodeJS back-end and I'm currently stuck with a security issue.

For my website to function, I need to login using a 3rd party service that requires a username, password, and security code. I have to be able to sign in to multiple accounts multiple times automatically throughout the day for my website to function. I'm not storing any user information, this is my own account info.

So obviously storing everything in plain text in one of my classes is a bad idea, so what would be the best way to store my login information? Would having a database that can only be accessed locally with the data inside be a good option? As I said before, it has to be able to automatically login so I'm not sure if hashing it would work since the code will have to decrypt it anyways so if my code is ever exposed, will it really matter?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is my own personal information as I mentioned, not my user's data. I need to be able to login with my own credentials to a 3rd party. Users login with a different 3rd party, we don't get any user data whatsoever

Comment: Oops, my mistake, sorry. So you say your application needs to get info from other services using your credentials to the third party service?

Comment: I think what you are asking is equivalent to the question of where do you store api keys on your server so that your server can access data from third parties using their apis. Best to web search "how do I store API keys" as your uname/pwd is essentially an API key. There is a lot of advice out there on the web, so be careful :)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be pretty much the setup I had previously. Seems like what you and JBallin suggested are the best options. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re basically asking “how do I store secrets on my backend?”.

Locally you would use a .env file, which isn’t committed to version control, that stores your secrets (i.e. “USERNAME=JBallin”).

You would then use something like [dotenv](https://npmjs.com/dotenv) to extract those values into environment variables and use them on your backend.

In production, you would store these environment variables on the server (instructions depend on the deployment environment).

Comment: Using the environmental variables seems like a good idea, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not a good idea to store a password, because even if you encrypt it,
the encryption key is still somewhere in the server.
Have you checked if the 3rd party service offer auth flow as oauth or equivalent?

Comment: Yeah, there's no other way to auth. Has to be username, password, and an auth key. Really no way around that sadly :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a new technology - Password-Hardened Encryption (PHE) protocol – a powerful and revolutionary cryptographic technology that provides stronger and more modern security, that secures users' data and lessens the security risks associated with weak passwords.

[Virgil PureKit allows](https://developer.virgilsecurity.com/docs/use-cases/v1/passwords-and-data-protection) developers to interact with Virgil PHE Service to protect users' passwords and sensitive personal identifiable information (PII data) in a database from offline/online attacks and makes stolen passwords/data useless if your database has been compromised. Neither Virgil nor attackers know anything about users' passwords/data.

I provided you with the link where you can find out code-snippets for such langs as: Go, PHP, C#, Java